# Ubuntu 14.04 - Citrix 12.1 Run xenapp in windowed mode

Tags: citrix

Good evening all,

Is there a way I can force the Citrix client through xenapp to run in windowed mode? I have tried using the wfcmgr but it doesn't save my settings.

Many thanks in advance,

José

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open terminal:

gedit ~/.ICAClient/All_Regions.ini

Then edit lines 852/3 to your desired resolution.

DesiredHRES=1366
DesiredVRES=768

This will force Citrix to open in windowed mode.

Comment: This prevented me from losing my mind. Thank you.